# Best way to update nested array using immutability-hepler

Tags: reactjs, immutability-helper

I'm using immutability-helper to update state, in React. I used to update things like this:

```
const newElement = update(element, {
            x: {
              $apply: function(x) {
                return x * width;
              }
            },
            markers: {
              $set: element.markers
            }
          });
```

But what about updating a property, which is an array. Let's say **markers** is an array, if I create the **newElement** by using `$set`, it justs create a reference copy, hence, this:

```
newElement.markers[0].text = "sample"
```

will modify state. What would be the proper way to do that, other than this:

```
 const newMarkers = [];
          newElement.markers.forEach(marker => {
            const updatedMarkers = update(marker, {
              x: {
                $apply: function(x) {
                  return x * width;
                }
              },
              y: {
                $apply: function(x) {
                  return x * height;
                }
              }
            });
            newMarkers.push(updatedMarkers);
          });
newElement["markers"] = newMarkers;
```

Comment: have you looked at immer? I think it makes `immutability-helper` totally obsolete now https://github.com/mweststrate/immer

Comment: no I haven't. i'll take a look